# Docker+Gunicorn+Flask, I don't understand why my setup is not working

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, gunicorn

I'm trying to build a simple application with flask and I've decided to also use gunicorn and docker.

At the moment I have this configuration:

```
> app
    > myapp
        __init__.py
        index.html
    docker-compose.yml
    Dockerfile
```

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -b :8000 myapp:app
    working_dir: /app
```

My `__init__.py`:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This minimal configuration works and I'm able to access my application and get my index page.

What I don't like is having my app created inside the `__init__.py` so I would like to move the app creation inside an `app.py` file.

The new structure will be:

```
> app
    > myapp
        __init__.py
        app.py
        index.html
    docker-compose.yml
    Dockerfile
```

`app.py` will have the content of the old `__init__.py` file and the new `__init__.py` file would be empty.

This doesn't work. I get an error

> Failed to find application: 'myapp'

and I don't understand why.

Any idea about this?

Comment: [`test`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/test.html) is a bad choice for a package name, which might or might not cause your issue.

Comment: I will try to change it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first configuration, your Flask app was located directly in the package `myapp`; after you moved it, it is in the module `myapp.app`.

Gunicorn [expects](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html) the app to be specified as `module_name:variable_name`, somewhat like `from module_name import variable_name`.

Option one: specify the correct module path:

```
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn -b :8000 myapp.app:app
```

Option two: add the app back to `myapp`. In `myapp/__init__.py`, add

```
from .app import app
```

Note that if the variable and the module share the name, the module will be overshadowed (not a good thing, although not a critical either).

Comment: I read the documentation but I was not really sure about how things needed to be translated to my specific case. Thank you very much for your explanation!